# Change Facebook Canvas button from 'Go to App' to 'Login with Facebook'

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I created a facebook canvas. I'm looking for a way to change the canvas button from 'Go to app' to 'Login with Facebook' as shown on the attached pictures. Did some research but couldn't find anything on this matter. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have to take off the images as I still don't have up to 10 reputations :D

Comment: if you are talking about the FB default button, you can't do something to change it, because is generated by FB.

Comment: @Yan my question is how to change [this](http://lescracks.com/test/1.jpg) to [this](http://lescracks.com/test/2.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible? Please I need an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is an App that is embedded in Canvas: that's the "Go To App" one.

The other is a Website that is NOT embedded in a canvas, that's the "Login" one.

---

To change it, you'd need to use a custom login button to return the user to a holding webpage that is not in the Canvas. (You also need to set this "website" up in the Facebook Developers App settings page). From the landing webpage, you can kick the user back to the canvas once they've accepted the app permissions. Probably not worth the hassles for a button that no-one reads?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a respone=token parameter in the URL and it shows "Login with facebook" and not "Go to app"

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=publish_stream&client_id=198583033513325&redirect_uri=myUrll&**response_type=token**&display=popup