# Change Go to App button text to " Log in With Facebook " in Facebook App window?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook Oauth in my site. I have the button with following url

```
define('FACEBOOK_APPID','xxx'); // replace 123 with your app id
    define('FACEBOOK_APPSECRET','xx'); // replace abc with your app secret
    define('REDIRECTURI','http://www.test.com/index.php?request=facebookdata_Action');  
                 $facebook_dialog_url = sprintf("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&state=%s&scope=email",
                FACEBOOK_APPID,
                urlencode(REDIRECTURI),
                wp_create_nonce ('my-nonce')
             );
```

Given button link as

```
<a title="Facebook" class="fb_btn " href="<?php echo $facebook_dialog_url; ?>"><span>Facebook</span></a>
```

Evrything works fine. When user redirect to Facebook, By default I am  getting "Go to App" button in window.My requirement is to change "`Go to App`" button text to  " `Log in With Facebook`"

I checked this [URL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/)

But there is no step to change the button text.

Also i found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560439/change-facebook-canvas-button-from-go-to-app-to-login-with-facebook). But i could not understand the answer.

Is there any step to change the text ?

Kindly advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Facebook Canvas button from 'Go to App' to 'Login with Facebook'](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560439/change-facebook-canvas-button-from-go-to-app-to-login-with-facebook)

Comment: @Igy Actually i have given that question in this post. I could not understand it. Kindly give advice on this post

Comment: The answer in that question is fairly clear as far as I can see - canvas apps get 'Go to app' and websites get 'login with facebook'

Comment: @Igy So I need to pass "website" as parameter to oauth url ?

Comment: no, you need to configure your app as a 'website', not a canvas app

Comment: @Igy Okay Thanks Let me check my app settings

Comment: @Igy I check with my app settings,Where do i need to set viewmode as Website

Comment: Definately a duplicate (as I answered the previous one). Let me know if the answer needs improving and I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried with following link

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/facebook-js-oauth-popup-centered/index.html

I got the solution by using the script.